# Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $(T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n))$ is a basis for $W.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, $B_V = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ a basis for $V,$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W).$ Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $(T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n))$ is a basis for $W.$

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is invertible. Then $T$ is bijective, and in particular injective. Since the sequence $B_V$ is linearly independent, it follows that (by a theorem in my book) that $B_W = (T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n))$ is linearly independent also. By our assumptions, the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic, and so  $n = \dim V = \dim W.$ But $B_W$ is a linearly independent sequence of length $n,$ so (by another theorem in my text) a basis.

I'm having a little difficult with the converse direction. If I could get some help on that I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the other direction, you can find an explicit inverse to $T$. This inverse will be a map $S:W \to V$ and is defined by its value on the elements of the basis $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$.

What is a natural element of $V$ where you can send $T(v_i)$ ?

Comment: "What is a natural element of $V$ where you can send $T(v_i)$?" Is it $v_i$? What would I need to prove about this function? That it is well defined?

Comment: Yes, it is $v_i$. Then $S$ is well defined since you know where it sends the basis of $W$. So now, you only have to show that is the inverse of $T$, i.e., either show that $TS=Id_W$ or $ST=Id_V$.